# How to make the distance between two rows larger in array?

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, arrays

I found a  mathematical formula in `mathdesign` document, it looks good and elegant
[image]

When I try to type it as it looks, what I got is always not as good as origin.

The code I use is

```
\begin{equation}\label{test}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>\displaystyle c}
  \left|\frac{D(u,v)}{D(x,y)}\right|=
  \left|
  \begin{array}{@{}YY@{}}
    \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\
    \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
  \end{array}
  \right|
  \neq
  0
  \quad
  \text{and}
  \quad
  \left|\frac{D(x,y)}{D(u,v)}\right|=
  \left|
  \begin{array}{@{}YY@{}}
    \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\
    \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
  \end{array}
  \right|
  \neq
  0
\end{equation}
```

which produces
[image]

I think the distance between two rows are too narrow. How can I can get the result as origin?
Thanks :)

Comment: Arrays and tables share much, perhaps rummaging in tables (e.g. using `@{\hspace*{0.5em}}` between columns, the `@{}` construction *replaces* whatever separates columns) helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the distance between the rows by adding the optional argument to the newline command as in: `\\[2.5ex]`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{test}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>\displaystyle c}
  \left|\frac{D(u,v)}{D(x,y)}\right|=
  \left|
  \begin{array}{@{}YY@{}}
    \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\[2.5ex]
    \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
  \end{array}
  \right|
  \neq
  0
  \quad
  \text{and}
  \quad
  \left|\frac{D(x,y)}{D(u,v)}\right|=
  \left|
  \begin{array}{@{}YY@{}}
    \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\[2.5ex]
    \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
  \end{array}
  \right|
  \neq
  0
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works, I thought \\[*] not works in math mode, Thanks :)